# Strange issue with the biblatex's command \addbibresource{}

Tags: rstudio

My latex document has this simplified code (see below).

If I am running it (turning into a pdf file) on my PC via the R Studio, then the resulting file (screen shorts are at the bottom of this post) does not contain the Reference section as the `bib` file (`ref.bib`) is not recognized. It must be said that both files the `.tex` and the `.bib` are located in the same folder.

However, when I am using `www.overleaf.com` to turn the same latex file into a pdf document -- it **does work** fine! (see below).

My question then: it must be something wrong with my R Studio set-ups, isn't it?

The `.bib` file:

```
@article{sen1979,
 ISSN = {00130133, 14680297},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2231867},
 author = {Amartya Sen},
 journal = {The Economic Journal},
 number = {355},
 pages = {537--558},
 publisher = {[Royal Economic Society, Wiley]},
 title = {Personal Utilities and Public Judgements: Or What's Wrong With Welfare Economics},
 urldate = {2024-01-19},
 volume = {89},
 year = {1979}
}

@book{beck2000,
  title={What is Globalization?},
  author={Ulrich Beck},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Polity},
  url={http://www.jstor.org/...}
}
```

The `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    natbib=true,
    url=true, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

    \section{Foo}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{beck2000}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sen1979}.

    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: look if you can find the blg-file and check its content.

Comment: what you show is the expected output if you have not run biber to generate the bibliography

Comment: @UlrikeFischer there is a `.log` file, no 'blg` one. The R Studio has this messaging: 

`Compiling document with tinytex ... Warning: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'beck2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.
Warning: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'sen1979' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.
Warning: LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 20.
Warning: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Warning: Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
Warning: (biblatex)                Exmp
Warning: (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
completed`

Comment: there must be a .blg if you did run bibtex or biber. Check also files without visible extensions, your OS can hide them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did this: I run the `.tex` file via TeXworks. As a result there is a `.blg` file now, its content is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OLHVu6zIPraT6NBk8BUPZtgLBo4mhEUs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: looks ok. Now you need to find out why R studio doesn't call biber properly.

Comment: Via a trial-and-error method I came to this sequence of steps that lead me to some (back-door) solution: (1) first, I must run my tex file via TeXworks which does not produce pdf file for some reason, then (2) second, I must run again the same file via R Studio, which does produce a pdf file.  This is quite a strange solution.

Comment: you have presumably configured texworks to run pdflatex, biber pdflatex, but just configured R to run pdflatex, which would make yoru output quite expected

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the suggestion! I have very little knowledge of how to set-up R to run exclusively pdflatex, while disabling TeXworks to do that. Can you give some hints?

Comment: no idea. I don't use either. but if I saved your file as abc.tex I would type `pdflatex abc; biber abc; pdflatex abc; pdflatex abc` on the commandline. If you do that you will get a bibliography, if you just do `pdflatex abc` you will get no bibliography and `\cite` will just print the internal key, as you show.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks!